# Get the FileName and Path of the PowerPoint Presentation that the Excel is Attached as Object

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

**Goal**: To get the Path and FileName of the PowerPoint Presentation in which my current Excel VBA is attached in as Object.

The screen-shot below might explain better what I mean:

[image]

This is the code I used to have to find the needed Presentation in case there are a few Presentations open at the same time (but I'm not able so far to get the Presentation in which I'm located in - and I don't want to pass the Presntation Name) :

```
Option Explicit

Sub UpdatePowerPoint(PowerPointFile)

Dim ppProgram                           As Object
Dim ppPres                              As Object
Dim CurOpenPresentation                 As Object

On Error Resume Next
Set ppProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If ppProgram Is Nothing Then
    Set ppProgram = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Else
    If ppProgram.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        For Each CurOpenPresentation In ppProgram.Presentations ' loop through all open presnetations (check Full Name: Path and name)

            Dim CleanFullName As String * 1024
            CleanFullName = Replace(CurOpenPresentation.FullName, "%20", " ")  ' replace Sharepoint characters %20 with Space ("_")

            If StrComp(PowerPointFile, CleanFullName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                 Set ppPres = CurOpenPresentation
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next CurOpenPresentation
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

**Question**: Am I missing an Excel/Office "Trick", which "ties" the Excel File somehow with the Presentation it's located in ?  Maybe some other solution ?

Comment: not sure i understand, but something like this `ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes(3).OLEFormat.Object.application.activeworkbook.name` checking this against the workbook being called from  (my bound data from Excel is in a slide with 2 headers, and the 3rd is the data, so youd need to check for these type of objects on the slides)

Comment: Just to clarify - you want to be able to find a reference to the Powerpoint presentation file name and path, from VBA code within an Excel workbook, that is embedded within said presentation? You do not want to have VBA code in Powerpoint pass a reference of the file name and path from the presentation to the Excel VBA code?

Comment: @SteveES exactly, I can't have any VBA inside the PowerPoint, as I need to save it as .pptx

Comment: @ShaiRado It might be useful to make that a bit clearer in the question. It's a good one though, I have no idea!

Comment: @Nathan_Sav  but what if the PowerPoint where the excel file with VBA is embedded is not the ActivePresentation ?

Comment: Yes, so you'd need to check each slide in each presentation, so from `ppProgram.presentations`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines

```
Sub T()

Dim ppProgram As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppPresentation As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim ppSlide As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim ppShape As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim objExcel As Excel.Application

Set ppProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")

For Each ppPresentation In ppProgram.Presentations
    For Each ppSlide In ppPresentation.Slides
        For Each ppShape In ppSlide.Shapes
            If ppShape.Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Then
                Set objExcel = ppShape.OLEFormat.Object.Application
                if objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Name=activeworkbook.name then stop
            Else
            End If
        Next ppShape
    Next ppSlide
Next ppPresentation

End Sub
```